# ¿Cómo pintar background de un LinearLayout desde java?

Tags: java, android, color

Quiero pintar un background desde java y el color que quiero poner lo tengo declarado en el fichero colors.xml.

```
<color name="holo_orange_dark">#ffff8800</color>
```

Quiero asignar ese color al background de un `LinearLayout` desde java, osea desde el `Mainactivity.class` al `activity_main.xml`

Comment: Agrega el activity_main.xml para una respuesta más precisa, que tipo de contenedor principal tiene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con esto deberías poder darle un color desde tu clase:

```
LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.id_layout);
lLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_orange_dark));
```

El Layout debe tener el id en el fichero xml:

```
<LinearLayout
....
 android:id="@+id/id_layout"
/>
```

Si ya tienes un id asignado, utiliza el tuyo propio en ambos códigos.

Comment: vale muchas gracias, lo he probado y SOLUCIONADO!!!